# Are there requirements to unlock the masteries in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I recently came back to Guild Wars 2 and bought the expansion.

Now I have a Revenant on level 80, the only requirement I know of.

Are there any further requirements for me to level my masteries? If so: What are they?

Another question is where can I level my masteries, after the requirements (if any) are completed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mastery):

> The Mastery system is an account-wide progression system available once players reach level 80, the maximum level available.
>
> Mastery training progress is also account-wide, allowing progression to be made on any level 80 character that gains experience.
>
> When you unlock the mastery system (being level 80, owning Heart of Thorns, and completing the story chapter 'Torn from the Sky'),the Mastery panel will appear as the last (lowest) tab on your Hero panel, and it can also be accessed by clicking anywhere on the XP bar. XP will be applied to the active track.

As David Yell suggested, there are two Mastery sets, one for both Tyria (Core Game) & the other for Heart of Thorns (Expansion); these each contain various tracks.

Also, as MrLemon has rightly stated, the prerequisite for the Spirit Vale track (1st Raid Wing) is to ensure that the Vale Guardian has been killed.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are two distinct mastery 'sets', one for Tyria (core game) and one for Heart of Thorns (expansion), each containing various tracks. Depending on which part of the game you are playing in will impact which mastery 'set' you accrue points in.

Comment: @DavidYell That's much appreciated, Dave. Please feel free to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the Spirit Vale Mastery Track (for the 1st Raid wing) is not unlocked until you kill the Vale Guardian (the first boss of said Raid wing)

Comment: @MrLemon I have amended my answer to reflect both yours & David's comments.

Comment: And next month there will be third set of mastery points, with release of new expansion Path of Fire. It will be possible to unlock mastery points without owning HoT, thus without the need of the mentioned mission (but probably it will be needed to get equivalent first mission in PoF), however that will unlock only core and PoF masteries, for HoT masteries you will need to own HoT expansion.